# Uniqueness for a certain semilinear equation

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, elliptic-pde

Suppose that $(M,g)$ is a smooth compact Riemannian manifold with smooth boundary $\partial M$. Let $a \in C^{\infty}(M)$, let $k \in \mathbb Z$ and consider the equation
$$
\begin{aligned}
\begin{cases}
-\Delta_g u +a(x)u\sin u=0, 
&\forall \,x \in M,
\\
u(x) =k\pi+f,
&\forall\,x\in \partial M.
\end{cases}
    \end{aligned}
$$
Is there some $\epsilon>0$ depending on $k$ such that given any $f \in C^{2,\alpha}(\partial M)$ with
$$\|f\|_{C^{2,\alpha}(\partial M)} \leq \epsilon,$$
the above equation admits a unique solution $u \in C^{2,\alpha}(M)$?